# Why I'm I getting a 403 using Azure Service Management API?

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

I want to use the Azure API Management (`management.core.windows.net`) to reboot role instance (ref to Microsoft documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/compute/cloudservices/rest-reboot-role-instance) but I'm getting a 403 as a response.

Request:

```
https://management.core.windows.net/{subscription-id}/services/hostedservices/{hosted-service}/deploymentslots/staging/roleinstances/{role-instance-name}?comp=reboot`

Headers:
- Authorization: Bearer {token}
- Content-Type: application/xml
- x-ms-version: 2010-10-28
- Content-Length: 0

Body: Empty
```

Response Body:

```
<Error xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windowsazure" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Code>ForbiddenError</Code>
    <Message>The server failed to authenticate the request. Verify that the certificate is valid and is associated with this subscription.</Message>
</Error>
```

I get the Authentication - Bearer Token by calling (ref to Microsoft documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/azuread-dev/v1-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow#service-to-service-access-token-request):

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}/oauth2/token

Headers:
- Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Body: 
- grant_type: client_credentials,
- client_id: {client_id}
- client_secret: {client_secret}
- resource: https://management.core.windows.net/
```

Any idea? Any missing configuration on the request or Azure Portal side? Is the `management.core.windows.net` deprecated since I can use the `management.azure.com`?

Notes:

- I already configured the permissions on the Azure side: I created an `app registration` for this, with a secret used to give permissions as `contributor`;
- The `management.azure.com` API works with the Bearer Token. I can access other resources such as `https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscription-id}/resourcegroups?api-version=2017-05-10` but I can't access the `https://management.core.windows.net/{subscription-id}/services/hostedservices` resources.
- I'm testing this on Postman.

---

**SOLUTION**

The problem was related to the certificate configuration

```
$cert = New-SelfSignedCertificate -Subject "CN=Azure Management API" -CertStoreLocation "cert:\LocalMachine\My" -KeyLength 2048 -KeySpec "KeyExchange" -NotAfter (Get-Date).AddMonths(360)
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "strong-password-here" -Force -AsPlainText
Export-PfxCertificate -Cert $cert -FilePath ".\azure-management-api.pfx" -Password $password
Export-Certificate -Type CERT -Cert $cert -FilePath .\azure-management-api.cer
```

Attention to the importance of the certificate to be a `.pfx`

**CODE**

```
   var cert = new X509Certificate2( File.ReadAllBytes( "your-certificate-path.pfx" ), "your_password" );
            var httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler
            {
                UseProxy = false,
                ClientCertificateOptions = ClientCertificateOption.Manual
            };
            httpClientHandler.ClientCertificates.Add( cert );
            var httpClient = new HttpClient( httpClientHandler );
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add( "Accept", "application/xml" );
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add( "Host", "management.core.windows.net" );
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add( "x-ms-version", "2010-10-28" );
            var uri = $"https://management.core.windows.net/{subscriptionId}/services/hostedservices";
            Console.WriteLine( $"GET {uri} [{httpClient.DefaultRequestVersion}]" );
            foreach ( var header in httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders )
            {
                Console.WriteLine( $"{header.Key} {header.Value.First()}" );
            }
            var response = httpClient.GetAsync( uri )
                .GetAwaiter()
                .GetResult();
            var content = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()
                .GetAwaiter()
                .GetResult();
            Console.WriteLine( $"{(int)response.StatusCode} {response.StatusCode}" );
            Console.WriteLine( content );
            httpClient.Dispose();
            httpClientHandler.Dispose();
```

Comment: Are you adding the Authorization: Bearer <bearer-token> to the header of your call? It would be helpful if you add your code that is calling the API. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Yes @DanielBjörk Before I put this on code, I'm trying to make sure I have access by testing it through Postman. But I will update my question by adding the headers, authorization and body

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your description, you want to manage Azure cloud service. Azure cloud service is [Azure classic resource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/deployment-models). So we need to use Azure service management API to manage it. If we want to call the API, we need to do  X509 client certificates authentication. For more details, please refer to the [document](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/introducing-the-windows-azure-service-management-api/)

The detailed steps are as below

1. Upload certificate to Azure
   a. create a certificate

   ```
   $cert = New-SelfSignedCertificate -DnsName yourdomain.cloudapp.net -CertStoreLocation "cert:\LocalMachine\My" -KeyLength 2048 -KeySpec "KeyExchange"
   $password = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "your-password" -Force -AsPlainText
   Export-PfxCertificate -Cert $cert -FilePath ".\my-cert-file.pfx" -Password $password
   Export-Certificate -Type CERT -Cert $cert -FilePath .\my-cert-file.cer
   ```

   b upload `.cer` file to Azure(Subscriptions -> your subscription -> Management certificates)
   [image]
2. Code (for example, I list cloud service in my subscription  )

```
 static async Task Main(string[] args)
 {
   var _clientHandler = new HttpClientHandler();
                _clientHandler.ClientCertificates.Add(GetStoreCertificate("the cert's thumbprint" ));
                _clientHandler.ClientCertificateOptions = ClientCertificateOption.Manual;
                String uri = string.Format("https://management.core.windows.net/{0}/services/hostedservices", "subscription id");
                using (var _client = new HttpClient(_clientHandler))
                using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, uri)) {
  
                    request.Headers.Add("x-ms-version", "2014-05-01");
                    request.Headers.Add("Accept", "application/xml");
                    //request.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/xml");
                    using (HttpResponseMessage httpResponseMessage = await _client.SendAsync(request)) {
                        string xmlString = await httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                        Console.WriteLine(httpResponseMessage.StatusCode);
                        Console.WriteLine(xmlString);
                    }

                }
}
private static X509Certificate2 GetStoreCertificate(string thumbprint)
        {


            X509Store store = new X509Store("My", StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
            try
            {
                store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly | OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly);
                X509Certificate2Collection certificates = store.Certificates.Find(
                  X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, thumbprint, false);
                if (certificates.Count == 1)
                {
                    return certificates[0];
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                store.Close();
            }

            throw new ArgumentException(string.Format(
              "A Certificate with Thumbprint '{0}' could not be located.",
              thumbprint));
        }
```

[image]

Comment: We tried your approach but we keep getting the 403 error @JimXu

Comment: @juan Could you please use fiddler to catch your request?

Comment: Done but I don't catch anything abnormal there. Any suggestion? @JimXu

Comment: @juan Please refer to the document to test api : https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-paas-developer-blog/azure-cloud-service-download-package/ba-p/819730

Comment: Thank you @JimXu I followed the steps in that tutorial and we were able to make the requests through AzureTools>MiscTools. The certificate works with the MiscTools but not on the code receiving the 403 Forbidden.

Comment: Did you try uploading that certificate into APIM and using certificate auth policy?

Comment: Thank you @Vitaliy Kurokhtin. I figured out the problem. I updated my question with my solution to the problem.